# How to console log output in hardhat test?

Tags: hardhat

I'm using running hardhat tests. When I add console logs to the test cases, nothing actually gets outputted to console. Why's that?

Comment: Hi! `console.log` should be outputting text to the console the tests are running in. Could you edit the question to post the output of your tests, and maybe a code block from the tests with a `console.log` in it?

Answer (score 11):

When people report this, 99% the time it means that they are running `npx hardhat node` in one terminal and `npx hardhat test --network localhost` in the other, and they expect to see the logs in the second terminal, but it's actually shown in the first one. This happens because the output of `console.log` is shown in the process where the Hardhat Network is running.

This doesn't happen when you run `npx hardhat test` (without a `--network` param), because that uses the in-process hardhat network. That is, the test task and the network run in the same process, and therefore the output is shown in the same terminal.

I have [an explainer](https://hackmd.io/@fvictorio/hardhat-networks-and-providers) about this that goes more in-depth about what happens in these different scenarios, and others, under the hood.

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone else happens to come across this, I happened to run across this because I was using ganache for my network instead of `hardhat node`. Switching my localhost network to `hardhat node` instead of using `ganache-cli` revealed the console.logs

Answer (score 1):

There's limitations to what you can console.log out..

e.g, string, boolean, address.

but for example, you would not be able to console.log a `UniswapV3Pool` object

if you take a look at hardhat/console.sol file, you can verify data objects are accepted. I think you are limited to a max of 4 data objects per console.log.. e.,g `console.log(1, "a", address(this), 4)`

If not, the solidity compiler will throw a fit.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue recently and found a solution not listed here. Change your test command to `npx hardhat test --verbose`.